# DiscordJS v13 AudioPlayer is stuck on buffering when trying to stream audio from a youtube video

Tags: discord.js, ytdl

Here is the code so far for my discord music bot. I believe the bot has the appropriate permissions, and is able to join the voice channel of the person who called the "!play" command. The issue I am having is that I can't seem to figure out why the audio stream is stuck on the "buffering" state. The docs states that the "buffering" state should either go through or fail, but it appears to be stuck.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (message.content.slice(0, 6) == "!play ") {
        // check input to see if it is a youtube URL
        let input = message.content.slice(6);
        if (isYoutubeUrl(input)) {
            url = input;
        } else {
            formatInput(input);
            url = await searchVideo(searchTerm);
        }
        if (message.member.voice.channelId !== null) {
            const permissions = message.member.voice.channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
            if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
              return message.channel.send(
                "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
              );
            }

            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                guildId: message.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
            })

            const stream = await ytdl(url, { filter:'audioonly' });
        
            const player = createAudioPlayer();
            var resource = createAudioResource(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 });
            player.play(resource);
            connection.subscribe(player);

        } else {
            message.reply("You need to be in a voice channel to play music!");
        }
    }
})
```

Here is what comes up when I console.log the player itself

```
<ref *1> AudioPlayer {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  subscribers: [
    PlayerSubscription {
      connection: [VoiceConnection],
      player: [Circular *1]
    }
  ],
  _state: {
    status: 'buffering',
    resource: AudioResource {
      playbackDuration: 0,
      started: false,
      silenceRemaining: -1,
      edges: [Array],
      playStream: [OggDemuxer],
      metadata: null,
      silencePaddingFrames: 5,
      audioPlayer: [Circular *1]
    },
    onReadableCallback: [Function: onReadableCallback],
    onFailureCallback: [Function: onFailureCallback],
    onStreamError: [Function: onStreamError]
  },
  behaviors: { noSubscriber: 'pause', maxMissedFrames: 5 },
  debug: [Function (anonymous)],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's stuck on buffering? if you debugged your code please attach the debug logs to your question as we can't judge and answer adequately

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the stream was not the issue. I just needed to use the "getVoiceConnection" component from the "@discordjs/voice" package and broadcast the stream to that connection instead.